# How do I do multiple OPTIONAL MATCH in parallel in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am currently doing something like:

```
MATCH (s:Something)
OPTIONAL MATCH (t:Tag)<-[:HAS_TAG]-(s)
OPTIONAL MATCH (i:Item)<-[:HAS_ITEM]-(s)
OPTIONAL MATCH (w:Whatever)<-[:HAS_WHATEVER]-(s)
```

When I do a profile, I see that 3 optional expand for each OPTIONAL MATCH sequentially, wonder if I can speed it up by possibly doing it in parallel? Since its independent of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in these cases I often do

```
MATCH (s:Something)
WITH s,
     [(s)-[:HAS_TAG]->(t:Tag) | t] AS ts,
     [(s)-[:HAS_ITEM]->(i:Item) | i] AS is,
     [(s)-[:HAS_TAG]->(w:Whatever) | w] AS ws
```

which returns arrays, instead of null in case the OPTIONAL MATCH does not return anything. and often it's faster too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single `OPTIONAL MATCH` and use aggregation to produce a node list for each relationship type:

```
MATCH (s:Something)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)<-[r:HAS_TAG|HAS_ITEM|HAS_WHATEVER]-(s)
RETURN s, TYPE(r) AS t, COLLECT(n) AS nodes
```